# How do I access row number in Yii2 GridView ActionColumn?

Tags: gridview, yii2

I have some custom buttons in the actionColumn of gridview in Yii2. I need to add the row number to the button data. Here's what I have...

```
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn',
            'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'font-size:20px']],
        ['header' => 'Blue or Red',
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{blue} {red}',
            'buttons' => [
                'blue' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                    return bootstrap\Button::widget([
                        'label' => 'blue',
                        'id' => 'blue' . **ROW-NUMBER**,
                        'options' => [
                            'class' => 'btn-lg btn-dark votebtn',
                            'data-vote' => 1,
                            'data-row' => **ROW-NUMBER**
                        ]
                    ]);
                },
                'red' => function($url, $model, $key) {
                    return bootstrap\Button::widget([
                        'label' => 'red',
                        'id' => 'red' . **ROW-NUMBER**,
                        'options' => [
                            'class' => 'btn-lg btn-dark votebtn',
                            'data-vote' => -1,
                            'data-row' => **ROW-NUMBER**
                        ]
                    ]);
                }
            ],        
        ],
    ],
]);
```

What do I need to put in place of **ROW-NUMBER** to get the row each button is in?

Comment: what do you mean with "ROW:NUMBER"???   .. is a db value ?  .. is a column in your dataprovider ??  .. is the row index in the grdiview?? ..

Comment: The literal row number in the grid, as laid out by the serialcolumn.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your "ROW-NUMBER" is a valid model  value eg id

you an use $model->id if you have mode object

```
 'buttons' => [
            'blue' => function ($url, $model, $key) {
                return bootstrap\Button::widget([
                    'label' => 'blue',
                    'id' => 'blue' . **ROW-NUMBER**,
                    'options' => [
                        'class' => 'btn-lg btn-dark votebtn',
                        'data-vote' => 1,
                        'data-row' => $model->id
                    ]
                ]);
            },
            'red' => function($url, $model, $key) {
                return bootstrap\Button::widget([
                    'label' => 'red',
                    'id' => 'red' . **ROW-NUMBER**,
                    'options' => [
                        'class' => 'btn-lg btn-dark votebtn',
                        'data-vote' => -1,
                        'data-row' => $model->id
                    ]
                ]);
            }
        ],
```

or use  $model['id']  if you have an array

Comment: I'm actually looking to avoid using $model->id. $key returns the same thing. I'm looking for the row number in the grid, as laid out by serialColumn.

Comment: the row number of the grid is the $key content..  so just change $model->id with $key

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not. in this case, in the second row (2), $model->id and $key both return 3.

Comment: @MikelG  answer updated  with a suggestion for $index

Comment: function for button only accepts 3 arguments.

Comment: coorect  .. anyway  .. what do you meen with  "in the second row (2), $model->id and $key both return 3" .?? i don't understand .... the seriale column in  grid view is 1 based .. while the index and key are 0 based..so why you have want 2

Comment: Ok, let me try to explain a bit more. I have two models, with keys 23 and 78. In grid view, it will only show 2 models. I want data-row to be the locations of the models in the table generated by GridView, not their keys. So I want data-row to be 1 and 2 (row 1, row 2), not 23 and 78. Does that make sense?

Comment: If i understand correctly then you have nothing related to the models .. but you juts need  the index of the gridview ..if this is correct .. you could add  column  .and . using the value function render a raw html code that mimic a button/anchor with assigned  the gridview index

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain row number like follows:

```
'red' => function($url, $model, $key) use ($dataProvider) {
     $pagination = $dataProvider->getPagination();
     if ($pagination !== false) {
         $rowNumber = $pagination->getOffset() + $key + 1;
     } else {
         $rowNumber = $key + 1;
     }
     return bootstrap\Button::widget([
          'label' => 'red',
          'id' => 'red' . $rowNumber,
          'options' => [
          'class' => 'btn-lg btn-dark votebtn',
                'data-vote' => -1,
                'data-row' => $model->id
           ]
      ]);
}
```

[yii2 serial number](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/grid/SerialColumn.php)

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Getting some strange values. I have two models in my grid view, The $key for them is 1 and 3. Using the code up above, the $rowNumber ends up being 4, when I'd like to be 2.

Comment: I have no idea about your problem. but please visit the added link in my answer. I hope it would help.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this same challenge - please try this:

```
                'red' => function($url, $model, $key) use ($dataProvider) {
                    $list = ArrayHelper::getColumn($dataProvider->models, "id"); // get the list in serial format with the key as the value
                    $index = array_search($key, $list, true); // find the key, return the index
                    return bootstrap\Button::widget([
                        'label' => 'red',
                        'id' => 'red' . $index,
                        'options' => [
                            'class' => 'btn-lg btn-dark votebtn',
                            'data-vote' => -1,
                            'data-row' => $index
                        ]
                    ]);
                }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).